# Black screen after boot

Tags: intel-graphics, lubuntu

After I choose Lubuntu on my Grub nothing happens. The screen turns black, the keyboard lights up like it may be doing something, but over time nothing happens.

This started happening after I closed my laptop and opened it up again. Now Lubuntu will not boot at all.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely because of something known as framebuffer. In order to disable it try adding the kernel parameters `i915.modeset=1` or `i915.modeset=0`. In order to do this you'll need to restart computer, then press <kbd>Shift</kbd> to enter the grub menu, and when Ubuntu is highlighted press `e`. After seeing the line which has something like `linux_gfxmode` or something like that add one of those parameter to the line. Once you've done that press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

my mobo is Intel D2500HN which has only 1 VGA port and no LVDS-1
my distro: lubuntu 18.04
my problem description: 
4.15.0-20-generic: displaying FHD1920x1080 ok
4.15.0-42-generic: blank screen after a few lines appear after grub screen

~$ sudo lshw -C video
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Atom Processor D2xxx/N2xxx Integrated Graphics Controller

First to make sure your firmwares and module libraries are intact for i915

~$ modinfo i915
modinfo: ERROR: Module i915 not found.

======solutions=====
make sure that both your "/lib/firmware/i915/" and  "/lib/modules/'uname -r'/" are populated with files
I lost mine due to "apt autoremove"

## ~$ sudo apt install --reinstall linux-modules-'uname -r' linux-modules-extra-'uname -r'

After
~$ sudo modprobe i915

~$ sudo lspci -v | grep -A 10 -i vga
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor D2xxx/N2xxx Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Atom Processor D2xxx/N2xxx Integrated Graphics Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 28
    Memory at d0100000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    I/O ports at 20d0 [size=8]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: 
    Kernel driver in use: gma500
    Kernel modules: gma500_gfx

and finally settle your grub:

~$ sudo  /etc/default/grub

### video=LVDS-1:d  is disabling LVDS-1 port which some kernel version might be directing the video to that port on default despite your mobo might not have such a port available to you

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i915.modeset=1 video=LVDS-1:d"

~$ sudo update-grub

my problem solved, credit due to https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=145648
which in turn drew his solution from
http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.linux.mageia.devel/13667

I had spent many days trying to nail this issue. Hope my findings are of use to you linux supporters. Cheers